# Minimum gpu_mem on π2

Tags: pi-2, memory

The [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) claims, 16 MiB is the lower limit for the gpu memory size. When I set it to less than 32 MiB, start.elf won't run successfully. Everything I get is a repetitive four times blinking pattern on the green led.

How do I get it down to 16 MiB and still have it boot?

```
$ vcgencmd version
Oct 11 2015 16:16:21
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version cdea693c2a4280e4855643dc7840392d915f19b8 (clean) (release)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I use a dynamic split (see below), but I tried this in `config.txt`:

```
gpu_mem_1024=16
```

Boots no problem, and subsequently:

```
> vcgencmd get_mem gpu
gpu=16M

> free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         996840       27540      811084       12712      158216      937840

> dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] Memory: 988232K/1015808K available (5958K kernel code, 534K rwdata, 1648K rodata, 416K init, 757K bss, 19384K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
```

The numbers from the OS are not simply 1024 - 16 Mib and require some interpretation.

The number from `dmesg` does not mesh with the number from `free`, which gets its information from `/proc`:

```
> cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         996840 kB
MemFree:          823816 kB
MemAvailable:     938548 kB
```

The "free" and "availaible" numbers will vary slightly on consecutive reads for hopefully obvious reasons.  They're irrelevant here anyway and not be be confused with the "available" number from dmesg.

Why is the relevant number reported in dmesg (988232) slightly different than the one reported subsequently by the kernel (996840)?  The latter is not the former plus any of the breakdown from the "Memory" line, although I notice the "1015808K available" number is exactly 988232 + the "reserved" and "cma-reserved" fields.  CMA is "contiguous memory allocation" and it's probably all for the kernel (5958K is apparently just "kernel code"; it will have [slabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) of stuff set aside as well).

996840 KiB isn't a multiple of 1024 (MiB) but it is a multiple of the ARM page size (4 KiB).  It's also very close to 988232 + "cma-reserved", which makes the "reserved" figure a bit mysterious (perhaps that's actually for kernel slabs, and the "cma-reserved" is for userspace stuff, and/or [device tree needs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt)<sup>1</sup>, and/or this is just coincidence).

Somewhere in there is the 16 MiB belonging to the GPU.  Assuming there is literally 1048576 KiB of physical memory, the 1015805 is exactly 32 MiB less.  However, there could be [more hardware than just video involved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147546/25985).  Also, since [the CPU fundamentally structures the page table](http://elinux.org/Tims_Notes_on_ARM_memory_allocation#page_tables), it may be subtracted before the kernel starts based on available memory.

If I set `gpu_mem_1024=32`, I end up with 999424K available in dmesg, exactly 16 MiB less again (note the "reserved" figures don't change much).  The parameter in `config.txt` works as documented; your problem is something else.  I try to keep the firmware up to date, but evidently not quite as up to date as you:

```
> vcgencmd version
Oct  1 2015 20:56:48 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 5fdecad11966c4bfe1848493f7f5ae15a60627a3 (clean) (release)
```

<sup>1. Or not -- I tried booting w/ `device_tree=` (disabled; I normally have I2C on) and I ended up with 996892 total mem instead of 996840, but "reserved" and "cma-reserved" were the same.</sup>

---

Here's my usual dynamic split; ostensibly I use this because occasionally I plug in a screen, and there is a GUI installed.  However, I don't think that actually requires more than 16 MiB, it probably has more to do with my curiosity about the dynamic split and the fact that I don't care that much about a few MiB (see comments).

```
cma_lwm=16
cma_hwm=64
```

In this case, `vcgencmd get_mem gpu` always reports 64M, despite being booted headless with no GUI running.  I haven't tried taxing things to see if it will give those 48 MB back eventually, but long before you reach that point you'll have driven the system into the ground. Put another way, there is not much useful purpose to getting it lower.

Comment: There 16 million reasons getting to 16. If I could, I would drop the entire GPU memory.

Comment: Actually, spending extra 16MiB on video memory I'll never use is really painful if you think about it could have been used as e.g. fs cache. What do you mean with "have driven the system into the ground"?

Comment: Exactly because of the file/[page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).  I'd drop the GPU mem too, but I don't really care, because the significance of the cache makes the upper limit "soft" (or more coarse).  If you are really coming close to using all the RAM, you need more RAM, because you've crushed the page cache ("driven into the ground").  If you have 256 +/- 16 MiB of cache space, *that "+/- 16" is trivial because of how caching algorithms work* -- the most critical stuff will still be there.  If you have 32 +/- 16 MiB, it doesn't matter anymore -- you've crushed it.

Comment: I don't follow you on that. What's better? To have 16 MiB allocated by the gpu and never used, or to have 16 MiB spare for caches, prefetching, ram disks, whatever? Unused RAM is burnt RAM.

Comment: Of course. My point about caching algorithms, though, is that the +/- 7% (of 256) is going to represent the bottom (least significant) part.  Having or not having that is not going to impact the system anywhere near as badly as not having it if you crush the cache down to where it would have been 50% bigger -- but at that point, you've already crushed it way too much.   If you've used 992 MiB, it doesn't matter whether there is 32 or 16 free, there is not enough.  *There is no point where that +/-16 MiB is going to seriously impede the cache, but the cache is of useful size.*  Make sense?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, you probably shouldn't be using more than *approximately* 768 MiB, or else you need more RAM.  And that "approximately" might as well be +/- 16.   Applying the same logic to a larger system, I might say using > than ~3 of  4 GiB is less than ideal, in a general purpose, multi-tasking context, and 4.1 GiB is not going to make a noticeable difference, just like using 3.1 isn't.

Comment: I admit I am pulling numbers out of my ___ a bit here and there are conceivably contexts where that 16 MiB might matter.  But for most people doing most things it never will, so if you are just concerned about it in the abstract, don't be.

Comment: I'm not talking about "using" it in the meaning of having applications run and have the RAM filled with their stack and heap. Even if I "use" just 30, I'd rather have the 16 extra for caches and not for a gpu I don't use.

Comment: Well, as I said before I agree it would be nice to just disable the GPU altogether, but I can't really complain: no one has claimed you can, and the Pi is a very inexpensive, general purpose item (and I still insist the real value of a MB depends on the context).  However: I admit I did not bother to check the consequences of `gpu_mem_1024=16` when I intially wrote my answer as I just took your word about the problem, despite the fact that I was pretty sure I had used that at some point.  So I tried it again and have edited my findings in above.  Hopefully you will find them interesting...

Comment: After upgrading the bootloader again to version from 2015-10-23 it works.